# How does meta tag with attribute http-equiv work under the hood?

Tags: html, meta, http-equiv

I heard that the meta tag in html can be used to specify response key-value pairs, if so, how does it work under the hood? How does the server responding with html page understands the meta tag before the html parser parses it? 

**Example of the meta tag:**

```
<meta http-equiv="set-cookie" content="userid=xyz; expires=Wednesday, 08-Aug-00 23:59:59 GMT;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I heard that the meta tag in html can be used to specify response key-value pairs

In very limited terms.

> if so, how does it work under the hood? How does the server responding with html page understands the meta tag before the html parser parses it?

It doesn't. It is interpreted by the browser.

> Example of the meta tag

`cookie` is not a valid value for `http-equiv`. I think you meant `set-cookie` which is marked as **non-conforming** in the [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives) so you should not use it.

`”` is not a valid attribute delimited character either. You need `"` or `'`.

Comment: Yeah I was confused about the usage of cookie as it's sent in the request  headers but the example I posted is copied from http://www.mytoptutorials.com/html/tag/setting-cookies-meta-tag/.

Comment: @user547729 — They are giving bad advice.

Comment: The browser can only interpret the HTML after the server responds with the resource. When a response has already been recieved how does the browser even transfer those header field names with their respective values?

Comment: @user547729 — The same way as the browser transfers the `<title>` tag, and all the rest of the HTML. It's part of the response body!

Comment: I guess I'm asking it in a confusing way, sorry.  What I mean is that the HTML interpretation is initiated when the response has already been made by the server. Those response header field names specified in the meta tags is understood by the browser but isn't it too late for the browser to transfer those "response" header field names as the response has already been completed before interpretation.

Comment: Since the browser is **reading** the response and not sending it. No. It isn't too late.

Comment: That means meta tags cannot be used to transfer **response headers**, right?

Comment: @user547729 — No. That is why the attribute has **equiv** in the name. They are equivalent to HTTP response headers.

Comment: Ohh. Thanks alot!